# Scaling dynos... Couldn't find that process type (web)

Tags: python, python-3.x, heroku, deployment

I have deployed [an API](https://github.com/antoinecomp/PerfumeRecommender-API) which works fine locally.
But even though it is marked as "DEPLOYED" I get the following errors when I try to execute a request like this one:

```
https://perfumerecommender-api.herokuapp.com/perfume?features=elegant
```

I got:

```
2021-06-27T15:08:06.174179+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-06-27 15:08:06 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2021-06-27T15:08:06.174441+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-06-27 15:08:06 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2021-06-27T15:08:06.258937+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2021-06-27T15:08:06.426846+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-06-27T15:23:25.208942+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=perfumerecommender-api.herokuapp.com request_id=c966dd04-305f-4645-8a7a-cc44f164fb92 fwd="78.197.172.21" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-06-27T15:23:25.745498+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=perfumerecommender-api.herokuapp.com request_id=f9a4f60e-8ae3-4497-bf51-1fb260ef5ac9 fwd="78.197.172.21" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-06-27T15:24:08.967458+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/perfume?=sweet" host=perfumerecommender-api.herokuapp.com request_id=80f3429f-f689-499c-80d3-a4c7ce973eea fwd="78.197.172.21" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-06-27T15:24:09.299456+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=perfumerecommender-api.herokuapp.com request_id=a9972238-2218-43e2-8d62-62271948af97 fwd="78.197.172.21" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-06-27T15:24:37.632950+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/perfume?=gentle" host=perfumerecommender-api.herokuapp.com request_id=e4ddeb41-6f42-4c44-a919-6aed9ece3521 fwd="78.197.172.21" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-06-27T15:24:38.031269+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=perfumerecommender-api.herokuapp.com request_id=bac417d8-ed30-484f-8e2a-7670e5dfcd6a fwd="78.197.172.21" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-06-27T15:28:39.769150+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/perfume?features=elegant" host=perfumerecommender-api.herokuapp.com request_id=47785d2d-e8d4-49ae-b863-4b471e18a850 fwd="78.197.172.21" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-06-27T15:28:40.160223+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=perfumerecommender-api.herokuapp.com request_id=fad8201a-97f7-42f0-9a6b-e267f5182c42 fwd="78.197.172.21" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-06-27T15:37:56.833793+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=HEAD path="/perfume?features=elegant" host=perfumerecommender-api.herokuapp.com request_id=0c89e358-9db3-4751-a053-64e1a56551a8 fwd="173.212.203.156" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-06-27T15:37:57.059654+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/perfume?features=elegant" host=perfumerecommender-api.herokuapp.com request_id=1cbc752a-2632-4dff-b334-8c6413a3db30 fwd="173.212.203.156" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-06-27T15:37:57.332723+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=HEAD path="/perfume?features=elegant" host=perfumerecommender-api.herokuapp.com request_id=479f8082-f15c-41a9-b43b-bf32570fa291 fwd="173.212.203.156" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-06-27T15:40:15.835324+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/perfume?features=elegant" host=perfumerecommender-api.herokuapp.com request_id=bfb8430d-61a7-45f2-9d54-a22075b6c6ab fwd="18.215.158.31" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-06-27T15:40:15.997767+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=perfumerecommender-api.herokuapp.com request_id=cc71cd21-af3b-4d68-abe3-31f2a344159e fwd="18.215.158.31" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2021-06-27T15:41:03.525447+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=HEAD path="/perfume?features=elegant" host=perfumerecommender-api.herokuapp.com request_id=75acbf62-5fab-4a31-a6be-29547a00c801 fwd="217.182.175.162" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-06-27T15:42:34.066572+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/robots.txt" host=perfumerecommender-api.herokuapp.com request_id=b43ba44c-8076-4290-9f9a-73ae5c1e2f18 fwd="107.23.45.127" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-06-27T15:42:34.406889+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/perfume?features=elegant" host=perfumerecommender-api.herokuapp.com request_id=ef3f4f39-d793-4ec4-b6ef-38ae2b6c4e2f fwd="107.23.45.127" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-06-27T15:42:34.709268+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/perfume?features=elegant" host=perfumerecommender-api.herokuapp.com request_id=60138fea-c9cb-49c0-b1ea-fa518fce4ae8 fwd="3.81.125.242" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Is it because of the requirements?

```
Flask==1.1.2
Flask-Cors==3.0.8
Flask-RESTful==0.3.7
gunicorn==20.0.4
joblib==0.13.2
jsonschema==2.6.0
pandas
pickleshare==0.7.5
requests==2.23.0
requests-file==1.4.3
wcwidth==0.1.7
webencodings==0.5.1
Werkzeug==1.0.1
```

I deleted and added my Procfile and now I have an error 14:

```
2021-07-03T13:11:36.799997+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=perfumerecommender-a
pi.herokuapp.com request_id=25bc35a1-3e4d-4dd2-9a96-f167ba47e9df fwd="78.197.172.21" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Here is my `Procfile`:

```
web: gunicorn app:app --max-requests 2
```

I tried to determine the number of dynos that are executing but it seems to crash:

```
(venv) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Learning\API>heroku ps
Free dyno hours quota remaining this month: 993h 14m (99%)
Free dyno usage for this app: 0h 4m (0%)
For more information on dyno sleeping and how to upgrade, see:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-sleeping

=== web (Free): gunicorn (1)
web.1: crashed 2021/07/03 16:11:21 +0200 (~ 1m ago)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In heroku you cant run any project without  declaring `Procfile`.
The `Procfile` tell heroku how to run your project.

Comment: Yeah, I have one. I just added mine to show you in my question

Comment: Hey I tried to deploy  by using this `web: gunicorn main:app` its worked but its shows this error https://nekobin.com/yoduyapoco . There are still some module missing in requirements.txt

Comment: I think you messed name in Procfile.

Comment: Thanks for your help Rishu! Indeed, I just removed this library on the git. Unfortunately, My deployment doesn't work ... Despite using `web: gunicorn main:app` in my Procfile